# Adding current form to AddFormToManager : MaterialSkin Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to use MaterialSkin.2 2.3.1 on my forms with net4.5 library. This is the code I am trying to follow:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

// Import the Material Skin
using MaterialSkin;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;

namespace Sandbox
{
    public partial class Form1 : MaterialForm
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // Create a material theme manager and add the form to manage (this)
            MaterialSkinManager materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;

            // Configure color schema
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(
                Primary.Blue400, Primary.Blue500,
                Primary.Blue500, Accent.LightBlue200,
                TextShade.WHITE
            );
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is the line which is giving me errors:

```
materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
```

This are the errors I receive:

> error CS0026: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method or static field initializer
> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager:AddFormTomanager(MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm)' has some invalid arguments
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Snippet' to 'MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm'

I tried replacing 'this' with System.Windows.Forms.Form.ActiveForm.FindForm() and than I get a similar, but different errors:

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'MaterialSkin.MaterialSkinManager.AddFormToManager(MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm)' has some invalid arguments
> error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.Form' to 'MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm'

Is there any other way of getting form reference?

Comment: *cannot convert from 'Snippet' to 'MaterialSkin.Controls.MaterialForm'*: it appears that `this`, in your context, doesn't represent a Form that inherits `MaterialForm`, but something else -- Anyway, you have to specify what version of MaterialSkin you're using (e.g., `MaterialSkin.2`, version `2.3.1`) and the .NET version you're targeting

Comment: I have edited my original post with the informations. So i am using MaterialSkin.2 version 2.3.1 with net45 library.

Comment: @Jimi i edited my question. Can you, please, take a look? Thank you.

Comment: You have to post your real code, not the default boilerplate. Code that should make clear what the `Snippet` Type you see in the exception is and where it comes from -- Possibly, move from .NET Framework 4.5 to at least 4.8. Better if you can target .NET 6+